# why is the lambda order partially reversing in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, set

I wrote a simple script

```
numbers = (1,2,3,4)
srebmun = (4,3,2,1)
div = lambda x,y : x/y
result = map(div,numbers,srebmun)
divNum = set(result)
print(divNum)
```

I expected the top numbers to be divided by the bottom numbers so (1/4,2/3,3/2,4/1) but instead I get 1/4,2/3,4/1,3/2 ({0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 4.0, 1.5}). Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: sets aren't ordered? if you want an order try `list(result)`

Comment: What is the excepted output?

Comment: -2 points for missing something obvious haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `set` is not ordered. You can either cast the result to a list instead of a set and keep the order or use a custom `OrderedSet` class

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned `set`s does not preserve order, you might convert your result to tuple following way

```
numbers = (1,2,3,4)
srebmun = (4,3,2,1)
div = lambda x,y : x/y
result = map(div,numbers,srebmun)
divNum = tuple(result)
print(divNum)  # (0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 1.5, 4.0)
```

or unpack your `result` (using `*`) inside `print`:

```
numbers = (1,2,3,4)
srebmun = (4,3,2,1)
div = lambda x,y : x/y
result = map(div,numbers,srebmun)
print(*result)  # 0.25 0.6666666666666666 1.5 4.0
```

Note that this by default use spaces as separator, if you want to use something else specify it using `sep` keyword argument, i.e.:

```
print(*result, sep=', ')  # 0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 1.5, 4.0
```

Note that this does exhaust `result` (you can not use it later again).

Answer (score -1):

A [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) does not have an order.

In this case it may be best to use a list comprehension:

```
[x/y for x,y in zip(numbers,srebmun)]
```

Comment: You are misleading - list on a map will work and keep the order of the items.

Comment: Hmm, for me using the above code `list(result)` returns `[ ]` but `list(map(...))` gives the desired result. Do you know where the difference is?

Comment: Have you consumed the map in `result` prior to your call of `list(result)`? If so, that's the cause. once a map is consumed it will be empty.

Comment: You are correct!  By copying the code and constructing the set the `map` had been consumed. Thanks for the knowledge!